# Divergence of Euler integral for non-positive arguments

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Why is it necessary that $\operatorname{Re}(x),\operatorname{Re}(y) > 0$ for the Beta-function

$$B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} dt$$

I suppose it is because the integral diverges when $\operatorname{Re}(x),\operatorname{Re}(y) \leq  0$? But what's so special about the threshold $\operatorname{Re}(x),\operatorname{Re}(y)=0$ ? In my eyes also $t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}$ diverges for $t\rightarrow 0$ but fulfills the condition.

Is there an intuitive explanation or an explanation for a person not familiar with the precise notion of integrable functions or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: For which exponents is $$\int_0^1 t^\alpha\,dt$$ finite? In the $B(x,y)$ integral, you have the same phenomenon at both ends of the interval.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528/123277) will help you a bit.