# If an event can happen with probability $p$, but I don't see it in $n$ tries, what is $P(p < p_0)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, bernoulli-distribution

How can I calculate the following:

Suppose I have an event (in my case, a computer bug) that can happen with unknown probability $p$. I run $n$ experiments and don't see the bug. What is the probability that $p$ is below some fixed value $p_0$?

(I am not well versed in this type of statistical analysis. From a bit of research I gather this is a Bernoulli process, and I saw some formulas for determining things like the probability of $k$ successes in $n$ runs, but not exactly what I am interested in.

This question occurred to me as I am considering how often one should replicate a bug to make sure it is a consistent bug and not a sporadic bug. Or how sure you can be a bug is fixed if you don't see it anymore.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the" probability without more input. You can calculate a number with Bayesian methods by making the following additional assumptions:

- First assuming a [prior probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) over the possible values of $p$. The simplest option is the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. If $n$ is large enough it doesn't matter too much which prior you pick.
- Then assuming that each of your experiments is independent. This is a strong assumption and in my opinion it's quite debatable whether it holds in this case, at least without putting in a certain amount of work to make sure that your experiments are "sufficiently different" from each other.

With those additional assumptions we can use [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to update on the observation that $n$ independent experiments don't produce the bug. The [posterior probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability) over the possible values of $p$ is then proportional to the [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) $(1 - p)^n$, which gives

$$\mathbb{P}(p \le x) = \frac{\int_0^x (1 - t)^n \, dt}{\int_0^1 (1 - t)^n \, dt} = \boxed{ 1 - (1 - x)^{n+1} }.$$

The median of this distribution can be computed by setting this probability to $\frac{1}{2}$, which gives $(1 - x_{\text{median}})^{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}$ or

$$x_{\text{median}} = 1 - \sqrt[n+1]{\frac{1}{2}} = 1 - \exp \left( - \frac{\log 2}{n+1} \right) \approx \frac{\log 2}{n+1}.$$

So this distribution is concentrated around $O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ which should be reasonably intuitive. You can also compute the posterior mean using the [Beta function integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/beta-function-derivation/3540#3540), which gives

$$\mathbb{E}(p) = \frac{\int_0^1 t(1 - t)^n \, dt}{\int_0^1 (1 - t)^n \, dt} = \frac{1}{n+2}.$$

This is a special case of [Laplace's rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: Cool, exactly what I wanted, including the two assumptions. I agree the second one is dubious, but this is still a good starting point to think about the problem.