# Calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^8x}\ {dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have started doing integration by parts:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^8(x)}{dx}
 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^7(x)}\cdot{\sin(x)dx}
 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^7(x)}\cdot{d(-\cos(x))}
 = \left. -\cos(x) \cdot \sin^7(x) \right|_0^{2\pi}
   + \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos(x)}{d(\sin^7(x))}
 = \left. -\cos(x) \cdot \sin^7(x) \right|_0^{2\pi}
   + \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos^2(x) \cdot 7 \cdot \sin^6(x)}{dx} = \dots$$

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Use integration by reduction formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the average of $\sin^{100} (x)$ in 5 minutes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24533/find-the-average-of-sin100-x-in-5-minutes)

Comment: Wallis integrals...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^8xdx
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^8dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}2^{-8}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^8dx\\
&=2^{-8}\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}(e^{ix})^k(-e^{-ix})^{8-k}dx\\\
&=2^{-8}\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}(-1)^{8-k}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(2k-8)x}dx\\
&=2^{-8}\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}(-1)^{k}2\pi\delta_{2k-8,0}\\
&=2^{-8}\binom{8}{4}(-1)^{4}2\pi\\
&=\frac{\binom{8}{4}}{2^7}\pi
\end{align}
$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24533/find-the-average-of-sin100-x-in-5-minutes ?

Comment: @chubakueno ok, we can close that question as duplicate

Comment: I don't understand why $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{e^{i(2k-8)x}}{dx} = 2\pi\delta_{2k-8,0}$

Comment: same where did you get the delta from?

Comment: This last comment of @Norbert is missing an integral sign and a dx. The left side is supposed to be $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx}\,dx$. If $n$ is $0$, you just have a constant $1$ function. Otherwise you can antidifferentiate to $\frac1{in}e^{inx}$.

Comment: @SergeyFilkin $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}dx=\begin{cases}2\pi\quad &n=0\\0\quad &n\neq0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @alex.jordan thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combination of
$$
\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{2} , \cos^2 \theta = \frac{1 + \cos 2\theta}{2}
$$
or an one of an assortment of other reduction formulas found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula).

I personally use the basic power reduction formulas (what I listed above) in order to practice my trig/algebra ;D

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$
\text{B}(x,y)=2\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}(\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}\ d\theta=\frac{\Gamma(x)\cdot\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}.
$$
Rewrite
$$
\int_0^{\large2\pi}\sin^8x\ dx=4\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\sin^8 x\ dx,
$$
then
$$
\int_0^{\large2\pi}\sin^8x\ dx=2\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac92\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\dfrac12\right)}{\Gamma(5)}=2\cdot\frac{\dfrac72\cdot\dfrac52\cdot\dfrac32\cdot\dfrac12\cdot\Gamma^2\left(\dfrac12\right)}{4!}=\large\color{blue}{\frac{35}{64}\pi},
$$
where $\Gamma(n+1)=n\cdot\Gamma(n)$ and $\Gamma\left(\dfrac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2n}x\ dx=\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2n}x\ dx+\int_\pi^{2\pi}\sin^{2n}x\ dx$$

Set $y=x-\pi$ in the second integral

$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2n}x\ dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin^{2n}x\ dx+\int_{\frac\pi2}^\pi\sin^{2n}x\ dx$$

Set $z=\pi-x$ in the second integral

Finally use [Reduction formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reduction_Formula_for_Definite_Integral_of_Power_of_Sine/Corollary_1)