# Understanding why $\int_{-a}^a \sin^{100}x\,\mathrm dx = \frac{99}{100} \int_{-a}^a \sin^{98}x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

In an answer here on Math.SE it is claimed that
$$\int_{-a}^a \sin^{100}x\,\mathrm dx = \frac{99}{100} \int_{-a}^a \sin^{98}x\,\mathrm dx$$
but I don't understand how it could be.

Since
$$    \begin{aligned}
        \int \sin^n x\,\mathrm dx &= -\cos x\sin^{n - 1} x + (n - 1)
            \int \cos^2 x\sin^{n - 2}\,\mathrm dx =\\
        &= -\cos x\sin^{n - 1} x + (n - 1)
            \int(1 - \sin^2 x)\sin^{n - 2} x\,\mathrm dx =\\
        &= -\cos x\sin^{n - 1} x + (n - 1)\int\sin^{n - 2} x\,\mathrm dx -
            (n - 1)\int\sin^n x\,\mathrm dx =\\
        &= -\frac{\cos x\sin^{n - 1} x}n + \frac{n - 1}n
            \int\sin^{n - 2} x\,\mathrm dx,
    \end{aligned}
$$
and for $n$ even
$$-\frac{\cos x\sin^{n - 1} x}n$$
is odd, how can it disappear from the result? What am I missing?

EDIT: For reference, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24538/2582) is the answer in question.

Comment: The result is not correct unless $a$ is an integer multiple of $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Winther: Ah, that's what I was suspecting. Actually the author later considers the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, so it's probably a typo.

Comment: I made some experiments with $\int_{-1}^1$ and it doesn't hold..