# Question on average value of $\sin^{100}(x)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I was looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24539/995613) answer but ran into some problems while working through it. Using $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ :

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^{100}(x)\, dx}&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{100}(2i)^{-100}\, dx}\\&=\frac{1}{2^{101}\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100\choose{k}}e^{ikx}(-1)^{100-k}e^{-ix(100-k)}\, dx}\\&=\frac{1}{2^{101}\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100\choose{k}}(-1)^{100-k}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{e^{ix(2k-100)}\, dx}\end{align}$$

Edit : Assuming the interchange is allowed at all

The exponent inside the integral ($2k-100$)  will be nonzero unless $k=50$, but from the answer if $k\neq0$ then the integral goes to $0$, no? How should this be evaluated?

Comment: Only $k=50$ contributes in  the final value.

Comment: Yes, the integral of $e^{inx}$ over $[0,2\pi]$ vanishes for $n\neq 0,$ as the antiderivative is equal $(in)^{-1}e^{inx}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn t the average value of any $n$for $sinx$ be zero?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz not necessarily because $\sin^{100}(x) \geq 0$

Comment: If the integral is calculated over $[0,2\pi]$ would it not make more sense to divide by $2\pi$ to get the average ?

Comment: @Peter sorry it was a typo, the average could be done with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but for this method it's easier with $2\pi$

Comment: @AnthonyML a typo in my post $sin^nx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If k is a non-zero integer than
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ikx} \, dx =\frac{1}{ik}\left[ e^{ikx} \right]_0^{2\pi}$$
$$=\frac{1}{ik}\left( e^{2ik\pi}-e^0 \right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{ik}\left( 1-1\right)$$
$$=0$$