# Differentiability of discrete-time Fourier transform

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

The [discrete-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) (DTFT) of real or complex numbers $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a Fourier series, which produces a periodic function of a frequency variable and is given by
$$
X(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x_n \,e^{-i \omega n},
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

I am interested in the differentiability of the DTFT. Is it a differentiable function? What conditions on $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ are needed for the DTFT to be differentiable? Is there an expression for the derivative? Can the series be differentiated term by term?

In particular, I am interested in the differentiability of the spectral density function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
f(\lambda)=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty\gamma_t e^{-i\lambda t},
$$
where $\{\gamma_t:t\in\mathbb Z\}$ are absolutely summable autocovariances of some weakly stationary random variables. Is $f$ a differentiable function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The condition $\sum |n x_n| <\infty$ implies differentiability: see [Rate of decay of Fourier coefficients vs smoothness](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30066). In practical terms, $|x_n|=O(|n|^{-p})$ for $p>2$ is often used.