# Can someone check my work on this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\log|e^{i\theta} - 1|d\theta 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-\cos(\theta))d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\log(\cos(0) - \cos(\theta))\,d\theta\\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(-2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-\theta}{2}\right)\right)\,d\theta\\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)\,d\theta\\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\log(2)d\theta + 2\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)\,d\theta\\ 
&= 2\pi \log(2) + 4\int_0^\pi \log\big(\sin(t)\big)\,dt\\
&=2\pi \log(2) - 4\pi \log(2) = -2\pi \log(2)
\end{align}
$$

Where $\int_0^\pi \log(\sin(t))\,dt = -\pi \log(2)$ according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37865/26920).  The first step where I removed the absolute value signs is the one that worries me the most.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget De Moivre's formula!

$$\begin{array}{c l} |e^{i\theta}-1| & =|(\cos\theta-1)+i\sin\theta| \\[2pt] & =\sqrt{(\cos\theta-1)^2+\sin^2\theta} \\ & = \sqrt{(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)+1-2\cos\theta} \\ & = \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}.\end{array}$$

Don't worry though,

$$\log \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}=\frac{\log2+\log(1-\cos\theta)}{2}$$

so there's not too much you need to modify in your computation.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks anon.

Comment: Well, not much to modify in the computation, but it changes the result rather significantly, namely to zero :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jensen's Formula, I believe: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensensFormula.html

**Edit:** Jensen's formula seems to imply that your integral is zero...

Comment: log|z| has a singularity at zero, thus it's not holomorphic in a neighborhood containing our curve.

Comment: The conditions in Jensen's Theorem apply to $f$, not to $\log f$. If you integrate around a circle of radius 1/2, Jensen's Theorem is definitely applicable.

Comment: Applying the correction in anon's answer also leads to zero.