# How to estimate $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\tan x)^{(1/y)}\log(\sin(x))\ dx$?

Tags: calculus

According to Mathematica
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\tan x)^{(1/y)}\log(\sin(x))\ dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$
but I don't see how to rigorously explain that. Could any help?

Comment: If you know Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, and if you are allowed to apply it, you can swap limit and integral.

Comment: @julien may I apply it safely?

Comment: For every $y\geq 1$, you have $|\tan x|^{1/y}|\log\sin x|\leq |\tan x||\log\sin x|$ on $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$, and $|\tan x|^{1/y}|\log\sin x|\leq |\log\sin x|$ on $(0,\pi/2)$. The latter bounding function is integrable. Indeed, it is continuous on $(0,\pi/2)$. At $0$, it is equivalent to $\log x$, so it converges. At $\pi/2$, it is equivalent to $(\pi/2-x)/2$, so it converges also. So yes, it looks safe. You can swap and get the integral given by @nbubis.

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as the sum of two integrals, one on $[0,\pi/4]$ and the other on $[\pi/4,\pi/2)$. Observe that
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}(\tan x)^{1/y}=1\quad\forall x\in[0,\pi/2).
$$
Moreover, on $[0,\pi/4]$  $(\tan x)^{1/y}$ increases monotonically towards $1$, while on $[\pi/4,\pi/2)$ it decreases monotonically to $1$. To justify that you can interchange limit and integral, use the monotone convergence theorem on each interval.

Comment: Monotone convergence can be used on $[0,\pi/4]$, but Dominated convergence works on $[0,\pi/2]$ for $y\gt\frac13$.

Comment: @robjohn I tried $\max(1,\tan x)|\log(\sin x))|$ as a bound, but the integration did not seem easy.

Comment: Near $\pi/2$, $\tan(x)\sim\frac1{\pi/2-x}$ and $\log(\sin(x))\sim-\frac12(\pi/2-x)^2$. Near $0$, $\log(x)$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the result of interchanging the limit with the integral, resulting in:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx$$
The answer of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x).

Comment: Is it?  Perhaps it happens to work out that way.  But the limit at $\pi/2$ is a major concern to me, and I'd like to see why your approach works.

Comment: It is a major concern to me too.