# Compute $\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}dx$$

This is a proposed for a Calculus II exam, and I have absolutely no idea how to solve it. Tried using Frullani or Lobachevsky integrals, or beta and gamma functions, but I can't even find a way to start it. Wolfram Alpha gives a kilometric solution, but I know that cannot be the only answer. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maple gives an answer of $\frac{\pi}{2} \ln (2)$.

Comment: Integrate by part first. If you don't know how to compute the remaining integral, look at answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37829/59379).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $y=\arcsin x\;\Rightarrow\;\sin y =x\;\Rightarrow\;\cos y\ dy=dx$, then
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}y\cot y\ dy.
$$
Now use IBP by taking $u=y$ and $dv=\cot y\ dy\;\Rightarrow\;v=\ln(\sin x)$, then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}y\ \cot y\ dy&=\left.y\ln(\sin y)\right|_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}-\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy\\
&=-\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy.
\end{align}
The last integral can be evaluated by using property
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ dx.
$$
We obtain
$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy=-\frac\pi2\ln2,
$$
where
$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos y)\ dy\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{by symmetry}.
$$
Thus
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}dx=\large\color{blue}{\frac\pi2\ln2}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> =-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
> =-{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\ln\pars{x}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-{1 \over 4}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
> =-{1 \over 4}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-{1 \over 4}\,\Gamma\pars{\half}\braces{%
> {\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}\,\bracks{%
> \overbrace{\Psi\pars{\half}}^{\ds{-\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}}\ -\
> \overbrace{\Psi\pars{1}}^{\ds{-\gamma}}}}\ =\
> \half\,\Gamma^{2}\pars{\half}\ln\pars{2}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\half\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}
> \quad\mbox{with}\quad\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\Gamma\pars{1} = 1.
> \end{align}