# How does one calculate $\int_0^1 \frac {\arcsin(x)}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I evaluate the following?
$$\int_0^1 \frac {\arcsin(x)}{x}dx.$$

Could not find a primitive, so I went for some other methods like arranging it as a double integral or introducing a parameter, but it was in vain...

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823923/compute-int-01-frac-arcsinxxdx).