# Integral $\int \limits^{2\pi }_{0}\ln\left| 2\sin \left( x\right) +3\cos \left( x\right) \right| dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I get the integration 
$$ \displaystyle\int \limits^{2\pi }_{0}\ln\left| 2\sin \left( x\right) +3\cos \left( x\right) \right| dx$$
I tried to solve it and find the close form but I couldn't. And I use W|A but it was useless.. my question is how I can get the close form for this integration?.

Comment: Why do you think there is "nice" closed form?

Answer (score 4):

What we have to do is essentially same as [Computing the integral of $\log(\sin x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x?lq=1), after a few steps of reducing your problem into this type by noticing $$2\sin x+3\cos x=\sqrt{13}\sin(x+\alpha)\quad where\quad \sin\alpha=3/\sqrt{13},\ \cos\alpha=2/\sqrt{13}$$
and $$\begin{array}{l}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|2\sin x+3\cos x|\mathrm{d}x=\\\int_0^{\pi-\alpha}\log(\sqrt{13}\sin(x+\alpha))\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\pi-\alpha}^{2\pi-\alpha}\log(-\sqrt{13}\sin(x+\alpha))\mathrm{d}x\\+\int_{2\pi-\alpha}^{2\pi}\log(\sqrt{13}\sin(x+\alpha))\mathrm{d}x.\end{array}$$
Note that the first term and third term of the RHS can be combined into $$\int_0^{\pi}\log(\sqrt{13}\sin x)\mathrm{d}x.$$ After all, we can obtain the answer by evaluating the above integral and multiply the result by 2.

Comment: (+1) The final answer is so $\pi\log\left(\frac{13}{4}\right)$.