# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi} x \ln(\sin x)dx.$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi} x \ln(\sin x)dx.$$

My attempt,

My first glance on this question I know that I'm going to use Integration by Parts.

So, it equals to $$-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} x^2 \cot x  dx$$

I've tried every methods that I've learnt for integration for this and I ended up in nowhere. Hope someone could provide a solution and explain for it. Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

Obviously, my attempt is wrong as the integral does not converge.

Comment: I am expecting a problem since close to $x=\pi$, $$x^2\cot(x)=\frac{\pi ^2}{x-\pi }+2 \pi +\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}\right) (x-\pi )+O\left((x-\pi
   )^2\right)$$

Comment: I checked with WA for the original integral, it equals to -3.42054.

Comment: Yes, and the definite integral you have after the integration by parts does not converge.

Comment: @Mathxx. Which is $-\frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 \log (2)$ but the result is not important. How to compute this integral ? The antiderivative of the initial function is just a nightmare.

Comment: Hoping there's someone who could solve this. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Parts isn't the way to go here.  Not only does the second integral diverge, but the "uv" part also diverges.

Comment: I totally support projectilemotion's suggestion.

Comment: Edited with your suggestion.

Comment: Hint : $\log\sin(x) = \log\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\int_0^{\pi} \log\sin(x) dx = -\pi\log 2$ (see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37865/59379))