# Evaluate $ \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{\arcsin{x}}{x} dx $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{\arcsin{x}}{x} dx $$

The answer should be $1.0887...$

I have tried several substituions which didn't work out and also thought of some series expansions

Comment: I think you need to use numerical methods to evaluate this

Comment: Change variable to $\theta = \arcsin x$, integrate by part and then apply
results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x). Your integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2 \approx 1.088793045151801$.

Comment: @achillehui: Exactly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Proceed in the following way:

$$I:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin (x)}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\cot (t)dt$$

by the substitution $t=\arcsin(x)$. Next, integrating per partes we get

$$I=t\cdot\ln\sin(t)\biggr|_{0}^{\pi/2}-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln (\sin(t))dt.$$

However, the last integral is a well-known one and his value is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\ln (2)$. Therefore
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\ln (2).$$

Comment: I have reached that integral after substition but I was dumb enough to not integrate by parts :s Thank you!

Comment: @SADBOYS: This can happen sometimes.