# Solving $\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1 - \sin^t x}{t}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

**Problem:**

> $$\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1 - \sin^t x}{t}dx$$

I have tried using L'Hopital Rule to calculate this but I could not go further. I also tried multiplying and dividing by $\cos x$ to force the by-parts rule but it was of no use either.

I would appreciate any kind of hint or idea towards the solution. As far as I am told, this problem isn't supposed to be very hard but I have given enough hours on it to come and ask here.

Comment: Try the lhopital rule to get the denominator as one in the integrand.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use lhopital on $$\frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} (1 - \sin^t x) dx}{t}$$

Comment: It seems that maybe:$$ \mathrm{\frac{\frac d{dt}1-sin^t(x)}{\frac d{dt}t}=-sin^t(x)(ln(sinx))\mathop {=}^{t=0} -ln(sin(x))}$$

Comment: Okay, so we are taking the limit inside the integral. Oh, yes! I'm surprised how I applied a similar thing in a previous problem and missed it here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that maybe:$$ \mathrm{\frac{\frac d{dt}1-sin^t(x)}{\frac d{dt}t}=-sin^t(x)(ln(sinx))\mathop {=}^{t=0} -ln(sin(x))}$$

Therefore:

$$\mathrm{I=-\int_0^\frac\pi 2 ln(sin(x))dx=\int_0^\frac \pi 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(sin(x)-1)^n}{n}dx}$$

I will evaluate this perhaps with a [series](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fty6k6araj).

Here is the rest of the evaluation [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x/2804742#2804742).

You will get the final answer as: $$\mathrm{I= \lim_{t \to 0}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1 - \sin^t x}{t}dx=
\frac{\pi}2 ln(2)=1.088793045151…}$$

Comment: The evaluation can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2804742/194169. You can add this in your answer so that OP can accept it.

Comment: I dont think we need any series, there is simpler computation to it and I know that part. I will accept the answer as is.

Comment: Yes, I see. There would have been a Hypergeometric function series to evaluate which I am not sure how to do. I will add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ \sin^t x - 1}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ e^{t\log(\sin x)} - 1}{t} =\log(sin(x))$$

which can give you convergence and thus you can interchange the limit and the integral.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I didn't see the comment when I posted the answer. If you think you can answer the question, please avoid doing so in a comment.

Comment: Yes you are correct.