# $f$ is a monotonic differentiable function and $F'=f$. Prove that: $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a monotonic differentiable function; $f: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$, so that $F'=f$.

I need to prove that:

$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$.

I tried to use the following formula: $\int u'v=uv-\int v'u+C$,
 but I can't see how I move on from this.

Any Hints?

Thanks A Lot!

Comment: One idea is to just differentiate both sides and verify. =)

Comment: $f^{-1}(x) \neq \frac{1}{f(x)}$!

Comment: @N.S.: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f^{-1}(x) = y$. Then $x = f(y)$ which gives us $dx = f'(y) dy$.

Hence, $$\begin{align}
\int f^{-1}(x) dx & = \int y d(f(y)) & (\because y = f^{-1}(x))\\
& = y f(y) - \int f(y) dy + C & (\text{Integration by parts})\\
& = f^{-1}(x)x - F(y) + C & (\because F' = f \implies \int fdy = F)\\
& = xf^{-1}(x) - F(f^{-1}(x)) + C & (\because y = f^{-1}(x))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. Can you please explain me why did you write that $ \int f^{-1}(x) dx  = \int y df(y)$. Isn't that suppose to be $\int yf'(y)dy$?

Comment: Plug in $x = f(y)$ in the integral to get $\int f^{-1}(x) dx = \int y d(f(y))$

Comment: So it's basically the same :) Why did I have to know that f is monotonic?

Comment: @Jozef: You need to know $f$ is monotonic so that $f^{-1}$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

[My Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/34977#34977) to this question should be helpful...