# Estimate the infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series

Explain:
What does the cartesian symbols mean?
Whats going on in here?
What topic of calculus is this?

\[
\large\prod_{i = 1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{1}i \right)^{(-1)^{-i}} = \ \lim_{n \to\infty} \prod_{i = 1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}i \right)^{(-1)^{-i}}
\]

Comment: Was this copy/paste from an online exam?  The verbiage looks like it...

Comment: What do you mean by "the cartesian symbols"? You seem to know that $\prod$ signifies a product.

Comment: It looks like the upper limit on the right should be $n$, not $\infty$ and this is just a definition of what the left side means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{i=1}^{N} \left(1 + \dfrac1i\right)^{(-1)^i} = \left(\dfrac21\right)^{-1}\left(\dfrac32\right)^{1}\left(\dfrac43\right)^{-1}\left(\dfrac54\right)^{1} \cdots \left(\dfrac{N}{N-1}\right)^{-1^{N-1}}\left(\dfrac{N+1}N\right)^{(-1)^N}$$
Hence,
$$\prod_{i=1}^{2N} \left(1 + \dfrac1i\right)^{(-1)^i} = \dfrac12 \dfrac32 \dfrac34 \dfrac54 \dfrac56 \dfrac76 \cdots \dfrac{2N-1}{2N}\dfrac{2N+1}{2N}$$
[Recall that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2N}(x) dx = \dfrac{2N-1}{2N}\dfrac{2N-3}{2N-2} \cdots \dfrac34 \dfrac12 \dfrac{\pi}2$$
and
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2N+1}(x) dx = \dfrac{2N}{2N+1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-4}{2N-3} \cdots \dfrac45 \dfrac23$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/20481#20481)
Note that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2N-1}(x) dx > \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2N}(x) dx > \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2N+1}(x) dx $$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-4}{2N-3} \cdots \dfrac45 \dfrac23 > \dfrac{2N-1}{2N}\dfrac{2N-3}{2N-2} \cdots \dfrac34 \dfrac12 \dfrac{\pi}2 > \dfrac{2N}{2N+1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-1} \cdots \dfrac45 \dfrac23$$
$$\dfrac{2N}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-3}\dfrac{2N-4}{2N-3} \cdots \dfrac45 \dfrac43 \dfrac23 \dfrac21 > \dfrac{\pi}2 > \dfrac{2N}{2N+1} \dfrac{2N}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-1}\dfrac{2N-2}{2N-3}\dfrac{2N-4}{2N-3} \cdots \dfrac45 \dfrac43 \dfrac23 \dfrac21$$
Can you now conclude what the answer should be?