# Variance of time to find first duplicate

Tags: probability, birthday

In repeated uniform sampling from $\{1,\dots,n\}$  the mean time $E(X)$ to find the first duplicate is asymptotically $\sqrt{n\pi/2}$. What about  the variance?

The variance is $E(X^2) -E(X)^2$.

$$E(X^2) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq \sqrt{x}) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \prod_{\ell = 1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor} \frac{n-\ell}{n}$$

$$ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \prod_{\ell = 1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor} \frac{n-\ell}{n} \approx \int_{x=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x}{2n}} \sim 2n$$

So $\mathrm{Var}(X) \sim \left(2-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)n \approx 0.43n$. Can we make this rigorous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use embedding procedures, as described 
for example in Chapter 15 of *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell.

You can derive correct asymptotics from the **equations:**

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X)     &=& \int_0^\infty   \left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n \,e^{-x}\,dx \\[5pt]
E(X(X+1))&=& \int_0^\infty 2x\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n \,e^{-x}\,dx. 
\end{eqnarray}

Your answer is correct, by the way.

---

**Added:** My cursory look at the literature suggests that the standard way to make these approximations rigorous *is* to write them in integral form, as I suggested, and then apply asymptotic techniques such as Laplace's method or the saddle point method.

For  the leading term, though, it suffices to perform the change
of variables $y=x/\sqrt{n}$. For $y\geq 0$, 
$(1+y/\sqrt{n})^n \exp(-y\sqrt{n})$ decreases to $\exp(-y^2/2)$ so by dominated convergence 
we get

\begin{eqnarray*}\int_0^\infty \left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n \exp(-x)\,dx
 &=& \sqrt{n} \int_0^\infty \left(1+{y\over \sqrt{n}}\right)^n \exp(-y\sqrt{n})\,dy\\[5pt]
 &\approx& \sqrt{n} \int_0^\infty \exp(-y^2/2)\,dy\\[5pt] &=&\sqrt{\pi n/2},
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}\int_0^\infty 2x \left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n \exp(-x)\,dx &=& 2n \int_0^\infty y \left(1+{y\over \sqrt{n}}\right)^n \exp(-y\sqrt{n})\,dy\\[5pt]
 &\approx& 2n \int_0^\infty y\exp(-y^2/2)\,dy\\[5pt] &=& 2n.\end{eqnarray*}

---

**Another addition**

*Checking that it works:*

Using the fact that [$\int_0^\infty x^j e^{-x}\,dx=j!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/20424#20424) for all non-negative integers $j$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n e^{-x}\,dx 
&=& \int_0^\infty \sum_{\ell\geq 0} {n\choose \ell} \left({x\over n}\right)^j e^{-x}\,dx \\[5pt]
&=& \sum_{\ell\geq 0} {n\choose \ell}  {j!\over n^j} \\[5pt]
&=& \sum_{\ell\geq 0} {n \over n} {n-1\over n} \cdots {n-\ell+1\over n} \\[5pt]
&=& \sum_{\ell\geq 0} \mathbb{P}(X>\ell) \\[5pt]
&=&\mathbb{E}(X).
\end{eqnarray*}

You should also look at Example II.10 (page 114) in 
*Analytic Combinatorics* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick,
freely available here: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html

*How they came up with it:*

We embed our sampling problem into continuous time as follows. 
Let $(N_j(t))_{j=1}^n$ be $n$ independent Poisson processes with rate $1/n$, each one representing a 
particular birthday. The first time $T_j$ when the $j$th process has its second event, we have observed 
two people with birthday $j$. As the sum of two independent exponential random variables, $T_j$ has a 
gamma distribution with density $xe^{-x/n}/n^2$ so $$\mathbb{P}(T_j>x)=\left({1+{x\over n}}\right) e^{-x/n}.\tag1$$

We are interested in the expected value of $T:=\min_j T_j$, the time of the first repeated birthday.
From (1) we obtain $$\mathbb{P}(T>x)=\left({1+{x\over n}}\right)^n e^{-x},\tag2$$
and hence $$\mathbb{E}(T)=\int_0^\infty \left({1+{x\over n}}\right)^n e^{-x}\,dx.$$

Now how does this compare with the discrete time version? Well, we can superpose all these Poisson 
processes $(N_j(t))_{j=1}^n$ into a single Poisson process with rate $\sum_{j=1}^n 1/n=1$.
Looking only at the types of events, and ignoring the time between them we recover our discrete time sampling 
process. In particular, we get $T=\sum_{i=1}^X Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are i.i.d. exponential(1) random variables and 
$X$ is the first time to get a repeated birthday under discrete time sampling. The $Y_i$'s and $X$ are independent, 
so by [Wald's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) we have $\mathbb{E}(T)=\mathbb{E}(X)\,\mathbb{E}(Y)= \mathbb{E}(X).$

An analysis of the higher moments gives $\mathbb{E}(T^j)= \mathbb{E}(X(X+1)\cdots (X+j-1))$ for all integers $j\geq 0$.

Comment: @Majid Sorry I don't have any reference besides the one I gave you. As for your question, you just have to check that the error at each step is negligible. Obvious, I know!