# Growth of $\Gamma(n+1,n)$ and $\operatorname{E}_{-n}(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

Quite often when I ask W|A to solve something it gives me an answer in terms of  $\Gamma(n+1,n)$ or exponential integral $\operatorname{E}_{-n}(n)$. Looking up the [definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/02/0001/) of the incomplete gamma function and the exponential integral I can get a formal definition but I have no feeling for how these function behaves.

What is the asymptotic behaviour of these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the definition:
$$
    \Gamma(n+1,n) = \int_n^\infty x^n \exp(-x) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Changing $x = n (1+t)$ we get:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \Gamma(n+1,n) &=& n^{n+1} \exp(-n) \int_0^\infty (1+t)^n \exp(-n t) \mathrm{d}t \\ &=& n^{n+1} \exp(-n) \int_0^\infty  \exp\left(-n \left(t-\log(1+t) \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The integrand is maximal at $t=0$. Expanding $t-\log(1+t)$ in the series around $t=0$ and using [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):
$$
  \int_0^\infty  \exp\left(-n \left(t-\log(1+t) \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-n \frac{t^2}{2}\right) \left(1 - \frac{n}{3} t^3 + n \frac{t^4}{4} + \mathcal{o}(t^5) \right) \mathrm{d} t
$$
giving 
$$
    \Gamma(n+1,n) = n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} \exp(-n) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} + \frac{3}{4n} + \mathcal{o} \left(n^{-1}\right) \right)
$$

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1,n) e^{n} n^{-n} \sim \sqrt{\pi n/2}$  . Is it obvious how to get the $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ from your solution?

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind adding some more details or a reference to somewhere with them please? It's not obvious how to do the "Expand in series and using Laplace's method" part. Or could there a simpler solution by some change of variables? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314220/variance-of-time-to-find-first-duplicate has a related integral solved that way.

Comment: Is it obvious how $\operatorname{E}_{-n}(n)$ and $\Gamma(n+1,n)$ are related from their definitions?

Comment: After a change of variables:$$ \Gamma(n+1,n) = \int_n^\infty x^n \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{d}x = n^{n+1} \int_1^\infty t^n \mathrm{e}^{-n t} \mathrm{d}x = n^{n+1} \operatorname{E}_{-n}(n)$$

Comment: Thanks (accepted answer). Do you  know if there are any texts online or in print that cover asymptotics of the sort you showed?

Comment: The [book by Olver](http://www.amazon.com/Asymptotics-Special-Functions-AKP-Classics/dp/1568810695) is good.