# Showing that $\int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x)dx=-\log2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need help with a textbook exercise (Stein's Complex Analysis, Chapter 3, Exercises 9). This exercise requires me to show that
$$\int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x)dx=-\log2$$
A hint is given as "Use the contour shown in Figure 9."

[image]

Since this is an exercise from Chapter 3, I think I should use the residue formula or something like that. But the function $f(x)=\log(\sin \pi x)$ becomes singular on $x=0$ and $x=1$, which makes the contour illegal for the residue theorem. Can anyone give me a further hint on this problem? Many thanks in advance!

P.S. This is my first time on Math Stack Exchange. If you find my post ambiguous, let me know.

Comment: I bet the contour is ever so slightly bigger than the box you've indicated, so that you can use the residue theorem. But if not, then you'll just have to use the definition and treat it as improper.

Comment: Note that, $z=0$ and $z=1$ are branch points.

Comment: The singularities at $x=0$ and $x=1$ are integrable.

Comment: @RonGordon: Could you explain "integrable" more? I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: If they are branch points, then how will it help to solve this problem?

Comment: For example, $$\int_0^1 dx \: \log{x} = [x \log{x} - x]_0^1 = -1$$

Note that the integral is finite despite log having a singularity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Consider $$f(z) = \log(1-e^{2 \pi zi }) = \log(e^{\pi zi}(e^{-\pi zi}-e^{\pi zi})) = \log(-2i) + \pi zi + \log(\sin(\pi z))$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(z) dz & = \log(-2i) + \dfrac{i \pi}2 + \int_0^1 \log(\sin(\pi z))dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \log(\sin(\pi z))dz + \log(-2i) + \log(i)\\
& = \log(2) + \int_0^1 \log(\sin(\pi z))dz
\end{align}
Now it suffices to show that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(z) dz = 0$. Consider the contour $C(\epsilon,R)$ (which is the contour given in your question) given by the following.

$1$. $C_1(\epsilon,R)$: The vertical line along the imaginary axis from $iR$ to $i \epsilon$.

$2$. $C_2(\epsilon)$: The quarter turn of radius $\epsilon$ about $0$.

$3$. $C_3(\epsilon)$: Along the real axis from $(\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$.

$4$. $C_4(\epsilon)$: The quarter turn of radius $\epsilon$ about $1$.

$5$. $C_5(\epsilon,R)$: The vertical line from $1+i\epsilon$ to $1 + iR$.

$6$. $C_6(R)$: The horizontal line from $1+iR$ to $iR$.

$f(z)$ is analytic inside the contour $C$ and hence $\displaystyle \oint_C f(z) = 0$. This gives us
$$\int_{C_1(\epsilon,R)} f dz + \int_{C_2(\epsilon)} f dz + \int_{C_3(\epsilon)} f dz + \int_{C_4(\epsilon)} f dz + \int_{C_5(\epsilon,R)} f dz + \int_{C_6(R)} f dz = 0$$

Now the integral along $1$ cancels with the integral along $5$ due to symmetry. Integrals along $2$ and $4$ scale as $\epsilon \log(\epsilon)$. Integral along $6$ goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$. This gives us $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{C_3(\epsilon)} f dz = 0$$ which is what we need.

---

**EDIT**

@Did has given the standard way to evaluate this integral using real analysis techniques. Here is another way to prove it.

From [integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/20481#20481)/ other techniques, we have that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k}(x) dx = \frac{2k-1}{2k}\frac{2k-3}{2k-2} \cdots \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{2} = \dfrac{(2k)!}{4^k (k!)^2} \dfrac{\pi}2 = \dfrac{\Gamma(2k+1)}{4^k \Gamma^2(k+1)} \dfrac{\pi}2$$

Hence, the analytic extension of $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2z}(x) dx $ is $\dfrac{\Gamma(2z+1)}{4^z \Gamma^2(z+1)} \dfrac{\pi}2$. (This needs to be justified)

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $z$, and set $z=0$, to get $$2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) = -\dfrac{\pi}2 \log(4)$$
Hence, we get that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) dx = -\dfrac{\pi}2 \log(2)$$
This also provides you a way to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n}(x) \log(\sin(x)) dx$.

Comment: Why do you use the multiplicative property of the complex log? I mean, in the first line why the equality holds if
$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ is not always true in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: For future readers and @alexp9 true, but we don't need to be so careful here. Two ways to see this 1) we know the integral will evaluate to a positive real, so there's no need to fuss about arguments; 2) since $\sin(\pi z) \geq 0$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$, we can write $\log(\sin(\pi z)) = \log(|\sin(\pi z)|) = \log(|e^{-\pi i z}(e^{2 \pi i z}-1)/(2 i)|)$ and work with the real logarithm.

Comment: @alexp9 it can be shown to be true for any $z\in[\delta, 1-\delta]$ (with $\delta > 0$). But of course it's not true in general.

Answer (score 20):

The integral $I$ to be computed is
$$
I=2\int_0^{1/2}\log(\sin\pi x)\mathrm dx\stackrel{x\to 1/2-x}{=}2\int_0^{1/2}\log(\cos\pi x)\mathrm dx.
$$
Summing up yields
$$
2I=2\int_0^{1/2}\log(\cos\pi x\sin\pi x)\mathrm dx=2\int_0^{1/2}\log(\sin2\pi x)\mathrm dx-2\int_0^{1/2}\log(2)\mathrm dx.
$$
The first integral on the RHS is
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\log(\sin2\pi x)\mathrm dx\stackrel{x\to2x}{=}\int_0^{1}\log(\sin\pi x)\frac{\mathrm dx}2=\frac{I}2,
$$
and the second integral on the RHS is easy, hence $2I=I-\log2$ and, finally,
$$
I=-\log2.
$$

Comment: Sorry, no complex analysis, simply the identities $\sin(\pi-u)=\sin u$, $\sin(\pi/2-u)=\cos u$ and $\sin(2u)=2\sin u\cos u$.

Comment: I assume the OP wants a complex analysis proof, which makes use of the specific contour he has in the question.

Comment: and I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Marvis Obviously, I am well aware that "the OP wants a complex analysis proof" and that the proof in my post does not use complex analysis since I signaled it myself in a comment.

Comment: I didn't see your comment when I posted mine. If you want, I can delete my comment.

Comment: (+1) a simple answer is a better answer. BTW, there is a typo in $2^{nd}$ line.

Comment: @achillehui A missing factor 2, I presume? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry that I tick @Marvis 's answer as the accepted one, because he uses the contour. But your proof is truly amazing! I always viewed real techniques are lesser than complex ones until I saw your post.

Comment: Please do not feel sorry, indeed the question asks for a proof using contour techniques and mine does not. Actually this would be a good MSE question: `Which, if any, integrals (of real-valued functions) are computable ONLY through contour techniques?`

Answer (score 8):

1. **Riemann sums**

It is not a complex analytic technique but I think it is worth mentioning. We can compute the integral by taking Riemann sums and exploiting the identity:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n}\tag{1}$$
from which it follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}\log(\sin(\pi x))\,dx &=& \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin x\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}\\&=&\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\,\log\frac{2n}{2^n}=\color{red}{-\log 2}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Other approaches deserve to be mentioned:

2. **Symmetry**

The function $\sin(\pi x)$ is symmetric with respect to $x=\frac{1}{2}$, hence
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I=\int_{0}^{1}\log\sin(\pi x)\,dx&\stackrel{x\to 2z}{=}&2\int_{0}^{1/2}\left[\log(2)+\log\sin(\pi z)+\log\cos(\pi z)\right]\,dz\\&=&\log(2)+2I.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3}$$

3. **An obscene overkill**

By [Raabe's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784529/integral-int-01-log-left-gamma-leftx-alpha-right-right-rm-dx-frac) $\int_{a}^{a+1}\log\Gamma(x)\,dx = \log\sqrt{2\pi}+a\log a-a$ and by the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)$, hence the question is trivial by switching to logarithms and integrating over $(0,1)$.