# An interversion problem

Tags: analysis

How to show that

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac1n \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2nx)dx \\ = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac1n \cos(2nx)dx$$

Classic Riemann and Lebesgue theorems seem not to work here...

Comment: Well, the upper,  sum is zero as all those integrals are zero...

Comment: When the upper limit of the sum (N) is finite, the equation is true.  Question becomes existence limit as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Ok for the left integral which is equal to 0 but the right side?

Answer (score 1):

Both sides have an explicit closed form. The LHS is zero so you can prove the right side is also zero: take the principal branch of the $\ln(\cdot)$ function, then

\begin{align*} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n} =&\Re \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2xin}}{n}\right)\\
=& \Re \left(-\ln(1-e^{2xi})\right)\\
=& \Re \left(-\ln(1-\cos(2x)-i\sin(2x))\right)\\ 
=&  -\ln\left|(2-2\cos(2x)\right| \\
=& -\ln\left(4\sin^2(x)\right)
\end{align*}

So

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n} dx =& -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(4\sin^2(x))dx \\
=& -\pi\ln(2)-2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(2x))dx \\
=&0 
\end{align*}

the last integral [is well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382085/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-this-integral) and has the closed form $\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$