# Why doesn't this approach work for integral of $\log(\sin(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math, book-recommendation

Evaluation of:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(\sin(x)) dx$$

Over closed rectangular contour $ABCD$ complex analysis.

Kind of like the contour here: [Contour Answer complex analysis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/integrate-square-of-the-log-sine-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-ln2-sinx)

[image]

**BUT INSTEAD** the right bound will be $\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$

Here is what I do **not** understand.

I will use the fact that

$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}) dx$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) dx - \left( \pi\log(2) + \frac{i\pi^2}{2} \right)$$

All we need to figure out now is:

$$J = \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) dx$$

Using that contour.

How can we do so?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying? $y=e^{ix}$ you have $e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=y-1/y=(1-y)/y$ and splitting up.

Comment: On another note, this integral is done by exploiting symmetrical properties of the sin function. No complex analysis needed.

Comment: @Alizter, I know it can be done without complex analysis. But I am interested in complex analysis. Which is why I posted this.

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x

Comment: @Amad27, see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080710/integral-of-log-sinx-using-contour-integrals.