# Integrate the following: $\int \frac {\log x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration

What I tried :

$$\int \frac {\log x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx$$

$$= \log x \int \frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx - \int \frac{1}{x} \left(\int \frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \, dx\right) \, dx$$

Now,

$$\int \frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \, dx = \arcsin x + c$$

But inputting this into the $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x} \int \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \, dx\right) \,dx$ 
 part is not getting me into a neat solution. Looks like there is some complex solution of the problem, but I don't know how to solve complex integration. What I did is :

$$\int \frac{1}{x} \int \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} \, dx\right) \, dx$$

$$= \int y \cot y \, dy \text{ where } y = \arcsin x$$

$$= y \ln |\sin y| - \int \ln |\sin y |dy$$

So will you plz help me in one of the two ways:

1. $\displaystyle\int y \cot y \, dy = \text{?}$ or $\displaystyle\int \ln |\sin y | \, dy = \text{?}$
2. Any better/neater solution of the original problem ?

I saw this question in MSE but in definite integral form, ([which is okay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080710/integral-of-log-sinx-using-contour-integrals/1080749#1080749)), but not sure about this indefinite form.Thanks.

Comment: Set $x=\sin y$  and use  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x

Comment: Yes I did $y = \arcsin x$ , I said, also this link again goes back to definite integrals.

Comment: Pulling $\log x$ out of the integral is nonsense, since the integral is with respect to $x$ and $\log x$ depends on $x$. $\qquad$

Comment: The most important thing here is that if ever anyone was begging for INTEGRATION BY PARTS, this is it.  Notice that you can easily differentiate $\log x$, getting $\dfrac d {dx} \log x = \dfrac 1 x$, and you can easily antidifferentiate $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, getting $\arcsin x$.  In integration by parts you have $\displaystyle \int u\,dv$, and you always differentiate $u$ and antidifferentiate $dv$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that we could find a closed form expression except using very special and complex function.

If $$I=\int \frac {\log (x)}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dx$$ just as you did using integration by parts $$u=\log(x)\implies du=\frac{dx}x$$ $$dv=\frac {dx}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}\implies v=\sin^{-1}(x)$$ then $$I=\log (x) \sin ^{-1}(x)-\int \frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\,dx$$ This last integral could be computed using Taylor series $$\sin^{-1}(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2 (2n+1)} x^{2n+1}\quad\text{ for }|x| \le 1$$ which makes, integrting each term of the expansion, $$\int \frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\,dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2 (2n+1)^2} x^{2n+1}$$

Just for your curiosity, this last summation corresponds to $$\int \frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\,dx=x \,\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};x^2\right
   )$$ where appears the generalized hypergeometric function.

What is amazing (at least to me !) is that this monster is quite "close" to $\frac{\pi   \log (2)}{2}x $.

**Edit**

Another possible way is to start with the expansion $$\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{\binom{2 n}{n} }{4^n}x^{2n}$$  That is to say that $$I=\int \frac {\log (x)}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{\binom{2 n}{n} }{4^n\,(2n+1)^2}\left((2n+1)\log(x)-1 \right)x^{2n+1}$$ $$I=x (\log (x)-1) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};x^2\right
   )+\frac{1}{9} x^3 \log (x) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};x^2\right
   )$$

Comment: Ah, yes, $_3F_2$, my old nemesis. It has popped up in my research. Definitely not a fun hypergeometric function.

Comment: @Claude , nice, but I don't know about hypergeometric function you mentioned at last, can you give some reference that I can read up ? Thanks

Comment: @Sayantani. I told that this was not simple ! Look at  http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/ and http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/17/ShowAll.html and http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/ and have fun !

Comment: @CameronWilliams. I don't know why but nobody really like it ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One does not need hypergeometric functions to find this antiderivative. It amounts to use poly-logarithms only. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx &\underbrace{=}_{x=\sin(u)}& \int \log(\sin(u) du\\
&\underbrace{=}_{t=\exp(\imath u)}& \int \log(\frac{t-1/t}{2 \imath})\cdot \frac{dt}{\imath t}\\
&=& \int \frac{\log(t-1)+\log(t+1)-\log(2 \imath t)}{\imath t} dt\\
&=& \frac{1}{2} i \left(2 \text{Li}_2(-t)+2 \text{Li}_2(t)+\log ^2(2 i t)+2 \log (1-t) \log (t)-2 \log (t-1) \log (t)\right)\\
&=& \frac{1}{2} i \left(2 \text{Li}_2\left(-i x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)+2 \text{Li}_2\left(i x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)+2 \pi  \arcsin(x)+\left(i \arcsin(x)+\frac{i \pi }{2}+\log (2)\right)^2\right)
\end{eqnarray}
In particular we have:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^1  \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = -\frac{\pi}{2} \log(2)
\end{equation}