# Compute $\int\limits_0^{\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos\left(t\right)\right)\ dt$

Tags: integration

I want to show that
$$
\int\limits_0^\pi \ln\left(1-\cos\left(t\right)\right)\text{d}t=-\pi\ln\left(2\right)
$$
I wanted to use the integral $\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \ln\sin\left(t\right)\ dt$ which I know the value but I struggle finding a judicious change of variable. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: This is equivalent to $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin(x)\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2) $ which has been asked many times. It can be proved via $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n}$ and Riemann sums, just symmetry, Fourier series, derivatives of the Beta function and probably many other ways.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

As $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=I$(say),

$$I+I=\int_a^bf(x)+f(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Now use [Showing that $\int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x)dx=-\log2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341643/showing-that-int-01-log-sin-pi-xdx-log2)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but could you provide a more detailed way ? I've shown the equality with $\log(\sin(\pi x))$ but I dont come up with the result