# Calculate $\int_0^\pi\log\sin\theta \,d\theta$ using contour integration only

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

Calculate $$\int_0^\pi\log\sin\theta\, d\theta$$ using contour integration only. I know the problem can be solved in multiple ways. But now I am interested in only the solution using contour integration. I have tried the usual techniques like setting $\sin\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta}}{2i}$ but with no luck. And it doesn't really seem like other integrals that can be solved using contour integration. Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help: [Showing that $\int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x)dx=-\log2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341643/showing-that-int-01-log-sin-pi-xdx-log2).

Comment: Rudin's RCA does this under the heading 'Jensen's Formula'.

Comment: using the symmetry of the sine function this seems easy to solve but not using contour integration