# Computing $\int_0^{\pi\over2} \frac{dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus

How would you compute$$\int_0^{\pi\over2} \frac{dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}\, \, ?$$

Comment: by residues, of course :)

Comment: how could one use residues? I can't seem to see where this function (if it were complex) has a pole!

Comment: Well you have to 1) use parity to extend the integration domain to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, then 2) express $\sin^2x$ in terms of $\cos2x$, and then 3) pass to the complex variable $z=e^{2ix}$ (contour of integration then becomes the unit circle $|z|=1$).

Answer (score 6):

Put $z=e^{i x}$; then the integral is equal to

$$i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{z}{z^4-6 z^2+1} $$

There are four poles at

$$z = \pm \sqrt{2} \pm 1$$

only two of which are within the unit circle ($z = \pm (\sqrt{2}-1)$).  The residues from each of these poles are equal and are each

$$\frac{i}{4 (\sqrt{2}-1)^2-12} = \frac{-i}{8 \sqrt{2}}$$

The sum of the residues is double that residue.  The integral is then $i 2 \pi$ times that sum; I get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+\sin^2{x}} = \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: He has only a quarter of unit circle initially.

Comment: @O.L.: That is built into my analysis.  The factor of $1/4$ cancels an equal factor in the denominator.

Comment: WHOA! How did you get the first bit?

Comment: $z=e^{i x}$, $dx = -i dz/z$.  Then use $\sin{x} = (z-z^{-1})/(2 i)$.  Do the algebra.  Note that you only have $1/4$ of a full circle in your integral, so you must multiply by $1/4$.

Comment: @RonGordon I get a $-1$ where you have a $6$ in the very first line. Are we totally sure that the $6$ is correct?

Comment: @TheCount: I am.  Apparently you are not.

Comment: @RonGordon No matter how many times I do it, I get $-1$. Sigh. Well, it is late. I should pick it back up in the morning. Thanks very much for the prompt reply - it helps me to be sure I have made an error in my own work somewhere.

Comment: Is there an explanation for why multiplying the integral by 1/4 is sufficient here to reduce from a full circle to a quarter circle? Is it true that if $\gamma_1$ is $\frac 1 n$ of a circle that $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) ~dz = \frac 1 n \int_{S^1} f(z)~dz$ for arbitrary $f$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2x}dx = \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{2}{3 - \cos 2x} dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{3 - \cos \theta } = \frac 12\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{3 - \cos \theta}$$

To evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3 - \cos \theta}d\theta$ let $\displaystyle z = e^{i\theta} \implies \cos \theta = \frac{z^2 + 1}{2z}, d\theta = \frac{1}{iz}dz$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3 - \cos \theta}d\theta = \frac 2{i}\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{-z^2 + 6z - 1}dz $$

The poles are $3 - 2 \sqrt 2$ and $3  + 2 \sqrt 2$, and since $3 + 2 \sqrt 2  > 1$,

$$\frac 2{i}\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{1 }{-z^2 + 6z - 1}dz = 4\pi \text{Res}\left[ \frac{1}{-z^2 + 6z - 1} , 3 - 2 \sqrt 2\right] = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} $$

So $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2x}dx = \frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\int_0^{\pi\over2} \frac{dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}= \int_0^{\pi\over2} \frac{\csc^2xdx}{\csc^2x+1}=\int_0^{\pi\over2} \frac{\csc^2xdx}{\cot^2x+2}$$

Put $\cot x=u$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{1+\sin^2(x)} & = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \sin^{2k}(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k}(x) dx\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{4^k} \dbinom{2k}k\dfrac{\pi}2 = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4\times \left(\dfrac{-1}4\right)}} \dfrac{\pi}2 = \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}
\end{align}
where we used

$\dfrac1{1+r} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-r)^k$; [$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k}(x) dx = \dbinom{2k}k \dfrac{\pi}{2^{2k+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/20481#20481); $ \dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{2k}k x^k \,\, \forall x \in \left[-\dfrac14,\dfrac14 \right)$