# Two versions of Taylor Series approxmiations, $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ and $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x'_0)(x-x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

My understanding of Taylor's Series for a function $f$ with a continuous $(n+1)$st derivative in a neighborhood of a point $x_0$ is that we can approximately have:

$$
f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)
$$

However, I have also seen formulations whereby we have:

$$
f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0')(x-x_0)
$$

whereby $x_0'$ is a value between $x$ and $x_0$. I am wondering why there are two different formulations and how to go between one and the other?

Comment: Mean value theorem probably, which will give $f'(x_0')$ to be a better approximation.

Comment: The second is not an approximation, it is an equality, given by Taylor's Theorem. Of course, $x'$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Oh right!  Wow, I am off my game XD  Well, I mean, I had the intuition, and indeed if you followed my comment...

Comment: What does $x'_0$ mean?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern "whereby $x_0'$ is a value between $x$ and $x_0$." Last few lines

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You were not off your game, if I remember correctly,  the proof of Taylor's theorem uses the mean value theorem. So you were not far off!

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yes, that's where my instinct came from, but my brain was not into it.  It appears my instinct is what I run on :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Stella Biderman's comment, I will post my comment as an answer. The second expression is an equality, not an approximation, given by [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).
The theorem states that if $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and $f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for all $t \in (a,b)$, with $P(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!}(t-\alpha)^k$, then there exists a point $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$ such that $$f(\beta)=P(\beta)+\frac {f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(\beta-\alpha)^n$$
for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ distinct points in $[a,b]$. This $x$ is the $x_0'$ in your second expression, where the theorem is applied with $n=1$.

Comment: Is this related to Taylor's Series approximation or a different thing altogether?

Comment: @user321627 It is related to the remainder formula for the Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @user321627 An interesting proof may be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20415/272831

Comment: Do you know where on the wikipedia page it states your version? I didn't see a mention of the existence part, thanks!

Comment: @user321627 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder where $\xi=x_0'$.

Comment: Does this imply that we can choose $\xi$ to be whatever we want or only the mere existence?

Comment: @user321627 Merely existence, but it can later be used to show that a Taylor polynomial converges to $f(x)$ if you prove that for all $\xi$ the remainder approaches zero.  (We also overapproximate with our $\xi$ to get approximations of a function through the Taylor polynomial + Remainder)