# Deriving Stirling's formula with big $O$ notation

Tags: calculus, logarithms

According to Wikipedia on [Stirling's  approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) :
$$ \ln(n!) = n\ln(n)-n+O(\ln(n))$$
I was able to derive the first part pretty easily :
$$\ln(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(i) \approx \int_1^n \ln(x) dx = [x\ln(x)-x]_1^n = n\ln(n)-n+1$$
I understand that $1 \in O(\ln(n))$ but why would you write the big-$O$ term ? I am surely missing something but I do not understand what? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23814/how-best-to-explain-the-sqrt2-pi-n-term-in-stirlings) question from 2011. Specifically, you might find [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eromik/data/uploads/papers/stirling.pdf) proof helpful. I believe your approximation of $\ln(n!)$ is too loose to give the precise error term.

Hope this helps,

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you are not using the same Stirling's approximation. As the approximation is $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, you can get the following:

$$
\log(n!) \approx \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right) = \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\right) + \log\left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right) \\= \log(\sqrt{2\pi}) + 0.5 \log(n) + n\log(n) - n = O(\log(n)) + n\log(n) - n
$$

By the way, you can find the detail of obtaining Stirling's formula in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) as well.

Comment: Omitting the constant prefactor, OP's statement equivalent to $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.