# On definition of gamma function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, gamma-function, bessel-functions

We all know that gamma function's definition is
$$\Gamma \left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty {s^{x - 1} e^{ - s} ds}$$
and it is divergent for
$x<0$.

Yesterday, I was studying about Bessel function and i came up with a dilemma. In Bessel function for negative numbers, i.e. $J_{-\alpha}$ they use a term like $\Gamma(m-\alpha+1)$ and when $m<\alpha-1$ series is defined although gamma function is undefined.
Also in class there were questions like finding $\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where it is a definite value? $$\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-2\sqrt{\pi}$$
but how is it well-defined, isn't it diverging? And how is it a negative number?

Summarizing, how exactly is gamma function defined?

Comment: No. It is defined for $x<0$. It just has poles on $-\Bbb N$, the negative integers.

Comment: If you are asking **why** it works then there are [many good questions on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/intuition-for-the-definition-of-the-gamma-function) to answer that. This essentially becomes a duplicate question.

Comment: It is defined as an analytic continuation. For example for negative $t$ you can always have $\Gamma (t)=\Gamma(t+n)/(t(t+1)\ldots(t-n+1))$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: @Alizter: What software did you use to plot the [beautiful graphic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6vBnT.png) from your now-deleted answer to this question?

Comment: @Lucian Google images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. The integral

$$\Gamma \left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty {s^{x - 1} e^{ - s} ds},\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$

converges only if $x>0$. Therefore the definition only works for positive $x$. However, one can use the functional equation
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$

to give a meaning to $\Gamma(x)$ also when $x$ is negative. Namely, suppose $-1<x<0$. Then $x+1>0$, so $\Gamma(x+1)$ is defined by $(1)$. Now we **define** $\Gamma(x)$ (for which the formula $(1)$ doesn't make sense) as

$$\Gamma(x):=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x}\tag{2}$$

You can already see that this definition makes no sense for $x=0$.
In the same way we can define $\Gamma(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (except $0,-1,-2,\dots$)
Namely, if $-2<x<-1$, then $-1<x+1<0$, so we already know what $\Gamma(x+1)$ is by $(2)$, hence

$$\Gamma(x):=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x}=\frac{\Gamma(x+2)}{x(x+1)}$$

In general, if $x>-n$, then

$$\Gamma(x):=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{x(x+1)\cdots(x-n+1)}$$

So you were interested in $\Gamma(-1/2)$. We get,

$$\Gamma(-1/2)=-2\Gamma(1/2)$$

which you can now calculate using $(1)$.

Comment: so it is defined as a recurring relation??

Comment: This is *one* possible definition and the easiest. The nice thing is, which you will understand if you study complex analysis, is that no matter how you extend the definition of $\Gamma(x)$, as long as it is *consistent* and *reasonable* in some sense, the resulting function will be the same. This is called *analytic continuation*.