# Intuition behind $(-\frac{1}{2})! = \sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: intuition, gamma-function

It can be shown that using the definition of the Gamma function as:
$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} dx $$ that $$\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$$ or slightly abusing notation, that $(-\frac{1}{2})! = \sqrt{\pi}$. Is there an intuitive explanation to this?

I want to make clear that I am not per se interested in a proof of this fact (most often these are clever technical manipulations) but in insight into this phenomenon.

Comment: I do not have the answer, but I was wondering how does one define the factorial of a negative non-integer value?

Comment: @YellowSkies: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gamma_function

Comment: I'm definitely not sure, but this seems strongly related to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/intuition-for-the-definition-of-the-gamma-function

Comment: @Dair, the second answer there does seem very related to this question, although still not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: See for example [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi).

Comment: The gamma function in *one* extension of the factorial function, a smooth extension (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Motivation). Therefor it's not fully correct to talk about $(-\frac{1}{2})!$ or $(\frac{1}{2})!$ etc.

Seeking for a function such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(x+1)=x\cdot f(x)$ leads to the function $\Gamma(x)$ if $\log(f(x))$ is convex, but I wonder if the gamma function has any combinatorial intuition?

Comment: It's related to [Wallis' product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider the area of the surface of the $n-$Ball with radius $1$ . 
It is given by:

> $$
> A_{n}=2\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}
> $$

Our intuition tells us that for $n=1$ the surface "area" (or to be mathematically more precise the, Hausdorff measure as @Michael Galuza pointed out correctly)should be 2, because it consist of two points. To make this consistent with the above formula we have to demand that

> $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: More strictly, "area" is Hausdorff measure.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I think you are right, but forgive i'm just a physicist with nearly no knowledge about measure theory.

Comment: I'm a physicist too;) I just thought that persons who like rigor can make sound about this “area” of two points

Comment: Alternatively, take $n=3$; then $A_n = 4\pi$ from which it follows that $\Gamma\left(\frac32\right) = \frac12 \sqrt\pi$. Then apply the fact that $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$, which for $x=\frac12$ says that $\Gamma\left(\frac32\right) = \frac12 \Gamma\left(\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 8):

> *Is there an intuitive explanation to this ?*

Yes. There is an umbilical [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_May_7#Linking_Factorials_to_Geometric_Shapes) between $\bigg(\dfrac1n\bigg){\large!}$ or $\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac1n\bigg)$, and [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) 
 of the form $X^n+Y^n=R^n\iff x^n+y^n=1\iff y=\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}$, whose area is 
 $\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}~dx$, which is nothing else than the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise. Ultimately, it's 
 all related to Newton's [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). The latter expands the **power of a sum** into a 
 **sum of powers**, with the help of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), or beta functions, which are then 
 expressed in terms of [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), or [$\Gamma$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 1):

$\color{red}{\text{beta-gamma function relation}}$

Notice, we know from beta function that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^m(\theta) \cos^n(\theta)d\theta$$ $$=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{m+n+2}{2}\right)}$$
Substituting $m=n=0$, we get 
 $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin(\theta))^{0} (\cos^n(\theta))^{0}d\theta=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{0+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{0+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{0+0+2}{2}\right)}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}d\theta=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(1\right)}$$

$$[\theta]_{0}^{\pi/2}=\frac{\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2}{2\times 1}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2}{2}$$ $$\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2=\pi$$ $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt \pi$$

Comment: Could some explain what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: Maybe because it was asked explicitly for an intuitive explanation? (i didn't downvote)